# Adding categories to all blogs at once

Tags: categories, multisite

I am using WordPress mu 2.9.2 and have the same category structure on all my blogs. How do I add categories to all my blogs simultaneously? Is there a plugin that does this effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script for that, here is something I wrote in Perl lately:

1. first the sql statements to check if the term already exist and if not insert it:

the prepared statements:

```
my $wts    = $dbh->prepare(
"SELECT term_id FROM $tb_wp_terms WHERE name = ?")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;

my $wti    = $dbh->prepare(
"INSERT INTO $tb_wp_terms
(name, slug) VALUES (?,?)")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;
```

1. then make the term taxonomy entry:

the prepared statements:

```
my $wtts    = $dbh->prepare(
"SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM $tb_wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = ? 
 AND taxonomy = '".$config{'wordpress.taxonomy_type'}."'")
 or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;

my $wtti    = $dbh->prepare(
"INSERT INTO $tb_wp_term_taxonomy
(term_id, taxonomy, count) VALUES (?,?,1)")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;

my $wtts_count    = $dbh->prepare(
"SELECT count FROM $tb_wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = ? AND taxonomy =
   '".$config{'wordpress.taxonomy_type'}."'")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;

my $wtti_count    = $dbh->prepare(
"UPDATE $tb_wp_term_taxonomy
 SET count = ?
 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = ?
 ")
or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . dbh->errstr;
```

And use the queries above with some code around it (you need to check for blogs that already have some of the categories).

For MU only the blogs > 1 get a blog id in their table name:

```
my $tb_blogid = "";
if ( $config{'wordpress.wp_mu_blog_id'} > 1 )
{
$tb_blogid = "_" . $config{'wordpress.wp_mu_blog_id'};
}
my $tb_posts                    = $config{'wordpress.prefix'} . $tb_blogid . "_posts";
my $tb_wp_terms                 = $config{'wordpress.prefix'} . $tb_blogid . "_terms";
my $tb_wp_term_taxonomy         = $config{'wordpress.prefix'} . $tb_blogid .     
"_term_taxonomy";
my $tb_wp_terms_relationships   = $config{'wordpress.prefix'} . $tb_blogid . 
"_term_relationships";
```

So just loop through them.

Comment: yes - writing a small plugin to loop through each blog works great, thanks for the code!