# How to create default categories in new installs?

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, multisite, customization

When a new user creates a new blog in WordPress MU I'd like to add a new category. How or where would I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the *wpmu_new_blog* action. [This question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/wp-multisite-adding-pages-on-blog-creation-by-default) is pretty similar, only that it creates pages instead of categories.

Comment: How about: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/adding-categories-to-all-blogs-at-once?rq=1 ?

Comment: OK I was trying to listen for the activate_blog action but it never seemed to be dispatched. Then again I might have had it in the wrong place. Is there a place I should add this add action code?